# How to secure my database access from angularjs side without nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, ionic-framework, pouchdb

For my Next Project (web + electron + ionic),

I want to use angularjs but don't want to use nodejs and for database.

I am thinking about pouchdb or google-firebase.

Now security is an issue for my database. like i have to connect with my database using angular because i will not use nodejs.

So i have to put my username and password on connection.

will my username and password secure ?

I am thinking that anyone who press `Ctrl+u` or from dev tool can see my user access.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yeah they can, using NodeJS (Or other server side language) is not optional, it is required. Unless you use build in firebase realtime or other database and write correct authentication rules there.

Comment: hey i need more information please provide me ? can you share a doc which i can follow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try angularfire2 library for firebase using this library no needed nodejs or any backend server. it's directly communicate with firebase.here is library 
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that you can't do that, you need some server side application to connect with the database in a secure way.
There is some gold rules you must always follow:

- There is no security from the client side.
- Never trust on information that comes from the client, even if you think it's validated.

Comment: hmm, thanks for an ans. but still i like to wait for 1-2 days than i will use node. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

**For the security purpose, you can go with firebase auth**

these are many secure login methods like

-FirebaseUI
-Password-Based
-Facebook
-Google.. etc

[reference link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start)- https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start

***If you are planning to use firebase for the huge database then one thing keep in mind firebase is not designed for the huge database it's limited.You can't compare firebase to SQL n MySQL etc databases. Firebase specifically designed for small databases.***

Comment: no no, i am working on chatting app, in which all chat logs will be deleted or zipped after 7 days. so it will be small db (FOR NOW). 
will move to mongo cloud in next version.
thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you grant write access for your chat clients by one hardcoded credentials (really easily get known) - you are on very dangerous side: one can quickly fill your DB with tons of garbage. There is no harm to hardcode read credentials (in order to separate access to different server DBs, i.e.) but for write ones you definitely need registration, which means Node or something. It will handle new users creation and give you ability to block unwanted client behaviour, just in case.